# Add a service worker to Webpack in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging

> If you’re using Create React App, Next.js, Gatsby, or a similar tool, you will have a Webpack setup out of the box to bundle your app.

So by default we have Webpack in React application, I want to add `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to my webpack configuration [to migrate to **modular** Web SDK of firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

How can I add `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to webpack of react that let me use `import` and tree-shaking

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) you just need to run

```
npm i firebase@9.1.1 --save
```

and you're done. (added `--save` so the change is added to your package.json)

Webpack is just a module bundler that will find the installed package and use it when you import it. Tree shaking will be done automatically by Webpack. So you don't have to modify the existing `webpack.config.js` (which would require you to eject the config first of all).

Comment: I am asking about web worker! `firebase-messaging-sw.js` service worker, not the react app itself!!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. [does this help you](https://dev.to/m3h0w/the-easiest-way-to-extend-create-react-app-service-worker-without-ejecting-bfg)?

Comment: YES! I think, thanks a lot @Taxel